# I am unable to enter the for loop when using xsl:param to render the value in variable and the using in for loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

```
 <p>Title: <xsl:value-of select="$section_map" /></p>
```

Note the above section_map variable is printing value `/form/medical-info/question-categories/question-category` .

Now i am trying to run my for loop by two ways:

1st way :

```
<xsl:for-each select="$section_map">...my code here ..</xsl:for-each>
```

2nd way :

```
<xsl:for-each select="/form/medical-info/question-categories/question-category">...my code here ..</xsl:for-each>
```

When i am using my for loop using first way. It is not able to enter insde the loop.

where as in second way it is executing fine.

Kindly tell me what could be the issue?

Kindly find the my xsl code here

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"
        doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" />
    <xsl:template match="/form">
    <xsl:param name="sectionMap" select="'medical-info'"/>

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

            <head></head>

            <body>

<form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" action="/admin/eapp/testForm">
<xsl:variable name="section_map" select="concat('/form/',$sectionMap ,'/question-categories/question-category')"></xsl:variable>
         <p>Title: <xsl:value-of select="$section_map" /></p>
        <xsl:for-each select="$section_map">

        </xsl:for-each>

</form>
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `section_map` is a string:

```
<xsl:variable name="section_map"
 select="concat('/form/',$sectionMap ,'/question-categories/question-category')">
```

how do you expect to `for-each` about it?

Maybe your should try `select="/form/*[name()=$sectionMap]/question-categories/question-category"` or some such instead?